# How can I put the feed import page on a different page and not have it on the node add page?

Tags: feeds

I want the user to be able to either add a new asset by using node/add or import a CSV, but on different pages. Right now both options come out on the add page.

How can I put the feed import page on a different page and not have it on the node add page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option on the Feeds importer edit page that lets you toggle off the form on the node add page. Just select the *Use standalone form* option on the **Attach to content type** setting.

[image]